# Any chance to make a loop with this code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

I have section in my html page where i put 9 images which displays dependingly on X mouse position (clientX). All works fine, but the only way i could code it its incredibly long and non-otpimal. Im sure it can be done more optimal by using loop or forEach method, but my skills not allow me to. Do you have any suggestions?

```
   const fotos = [...document.getElementsByClassName('mousemovefoto')];
   const startfoto = document.querySelector('.startfoto');

   window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {

const x = event.clientX;


if (x < 211) {
    startfoto.style.display = 'inline-block'
    fotos[0].style.display = 'none'
} else if (x >= 211 && x < 422) {
    fotos[0].style.display = "inline-block"
    fotos[1].style.display = 'none'
    startfoto.style.display = 'none'
}  else if (x >= 422 && x < 633) {
    fotos[1].style.display = 'inline-block'
    fotos[0].style.display = "none"
    fotos[2].style.display = "none"
    startfoto.style.display = 'none'
} else if (x >= 633 && x < 844) {
    fotos[2].style.display = 'inline-block'
    fotos[1].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[0].style.display = "none"
    startfoto.style.display = 'none'
    fotos[3].style.display = 'none'
} else if (x >= 844 && x < 1055) {
    fotos[3].style.display = 'inline-block'
    fotos[2].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[1].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[0].style.display = "none"
    fotos[4].style.display = 'none'
    startfoto.style.display = 'none'
} else if (x >= 1055 && x < 1266) {
    fotos[4].style.display = 'inline-block'
    fotos[3].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[2].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[1].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[0].style.display = "none"
    fotos[5].style.display = "none"
    startfoto.style.display = 'none'
}  else if (x >= 1266 && x < 1477) {
    fotos[5].style.display = 'inline-block'
    fotos[4].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[3].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[2].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[1].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[0].style.display = "none"
    fotos[6].style.display = "none"
    startfoto.style.display = 'none'
}  else if (x >= 1477 && x < 1688) {
    fotos[6].style.display = 'inline-block'
    fotos[5].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[4].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[3].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[2].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[1].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[0].style.display = "none"
    fotos[7].style.display = "none"
    startfoto.style.display = 'none'
} else if (x >= 1688 && x < 3000) {
    fotos[7].style.display = 'inline-block'
    fotos[6].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[5].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[4].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[3].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[2].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[1].style.display = 'none'
    fotos[0].style.display = "none"
    startfoto.style.display = 'none' 
}
})
```

I was trying this without all

```
fotos[x].style.display = "none"
```

but without it when foto is changing, previous foto goes under and i have 9 photos under each other on site.

I was also trying to add css class

```
.active {
display: inline-block;
}
```

and add/remove it with mouse move, but fotos were also displaying under each other after changing.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Now you can simplify those conditionals to a degree but are you sure that you are doing the right thing to start with? Perhaps you can have some `div` elements with the required heights those you can use to trigger hover event. Just an idea.

Comment: hover might be a nice idea, thanks. Will try to work with it if i wont find the loop answer

Comment: Could you explain the last condition (<3000) which does not follow the pattern of the other tests which are at set intervals.

Comment: Well i thought that someone might use bigger screen than mine so i wanted last photo to be displayed on wider screen too. Pretty dumb i guess

Comment: You could just have it that anything over 1687 shows the 9th photo.

Comment: Could you also show some of your representative "*[mcve]*" HTML and CSS alongside the JavaScript? That way you - and other future visitors with similar problems - are likely to get more useful answers. You would also benefit from more clearly explaining your problem; I can read what your code is doing, but that code (presumably) isn't working, which limits the hints that I can take from it. Consider reading the "*[ask]*" guidance.

Comment: I think minimal reproducible example wasn't necessary in this case. I paste code and said it works, then only asked for more optimal version of it with a loop. Everybody knows what i was talking about and Ma3x reply was exactly what i need. Of coure i will keep it in mind and will try to add minimal reproductible examples in my questions in th future, thanks

Comment: The site - and the answers here - exist to help everyone, not just you. Posting MCVE code isn't something that's nice to have, it's mandatory according to the rules of the site. Please: post the relevant code in order that *others* can learn.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you are using equal distance bins (of 211), you can turn it into a loop like this

```js
const binWidth = 211;
const k = Math.floor((x - binWidth) / binWidth);
if (k < 0) {
    // k < 0 when x < 211
    startfoto.style.display = 'inline-block'
    fotos[0].style.display = 'none'
} else {
    // k = 0, 1, 2, 3... 7 (when x >= 1688)
    for (let i = k + 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i < fotos.length) {
            fotos[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    fotos[k].style.display = 'inline-block';
    startfoto.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much, i knew it was doable with few lines of loop. Will try to practise with loops more now when i know how to do it. Again big thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fotos = [...document.getElementsByClassName('mousemovefoto')];
   const startfoto = document.querySelector('.startfoto');

   window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {

const x = event.clientX;

let p = Math.trunc(x/211)

if (p == 0) {
   startfoto.style.display = 'inline-block'
   fotos[0].style.display = 'none'
}else startfoto.style.display = 'none'

for (let i = 0; i < p ; i++){
    fotos[i].style.display = 'none'
}
fotos[p-1].style.display='inline-block'
  


})
```

Comment: almost. When X mouse position increase all works good, but then when i go back with mouse, all photos have display: inline-block; and appears under each other messing with whole page